# Persisting application settings using ClickOnce deployment

Tags: deployment, clickonce, configuration-files

I'm using ClickOnce deployment and I need configuration information persisting across different users and versions. I tried to use serialization/deserialization to a file located in the `Application.CommonAppDataPath`, but the path changes when changing either the major or the minor numbers of the publish version, hence preventing information to persist across different versions.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290201/file-permissions-across-user-profiles) a solution by adopting a user-based data path and by setting permission in order to allow access across different users. I would instead prefer a common path accessible by all the users and that does not change with versions. Does it exist?

EDIT:
The path should not need elevated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Vista and 7, there's the c:\ProgramData folder that's used exactly for that - placing computer-wide program-specific data. You need elevated permissions to use it, so I don't know if you can access it from a ClickOnce-installed-application.

However, my experience with ClickOnce is that for anything more than the most trivial applications, you're better off creating a full-fledged setup.

Comment: I would prefer to have a folder that does not need elevated permission as Application.CommonAppDataPath does