# Can you enable write access for the IUSR through the IIS web.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-4.5, iis-8.5

I have FTP/"control panel" access to a shared hosting environment and need to give the IUSR write access to a directory so that authorized users of the web may upload files to the server.

I am migrating an existing application and don't really want to rewrite anything to use the `App_Data` directory for storage and retrieval.

There is no mechanism in the control panel for setting up such permissions and I can't seem to connect remotely using IIS.

The environment is supposedly: Windows Server 2012 R2 / IIS 8.5 / .NET 4.5

As far as I recall, there is no mechanism in the web.config that would allow me to do this, but I might be wrong. So, can you enable write access for the IUSR through the IIS web.config?

Comment: There's nothing in the web config, but shouldn't a simple ticket to the hosting provider's help desk resolve this? They should be happy to help. Or, if you can run code with high enough permissions, grant the access yourself (*if it doesn't violate any ToS*): http://stackoverflow.com/a/518819/74757

Comment: As far as help desk, I am working on it, but it's a white-label situation and the middle man isn't capable to resolve it.  Intriguing idea to just set it myself.  I will have to look into it.

Comment: There must be another way of looking at this issue.  For comparison, I thought I would look at Microsoft Azure and in the Web App configuration there is no way to set the IUSR permissions there either.